# Jackson complains when deserializing a collection of polymorphic objects

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I've got the following hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "...")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true, defaultImpl = A.class)
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "B") })
public abstract class Base implements IJPAEntity<String>, Jsonable {
/*
   implementation
*/
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "...")
public class A extends Base {
/*
   implementation
*/
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "...")
public class B extends Base {
/*
   implementation
*/
}
```

Whenever I do the following deserialization everything is fine:

```
String testJSON = "{\"id\": \"someId\",\"description\": \"someDescription\",\"type\": \"B\"}";
Base b = new ObjectMapper().readValue(testJSON, Base.class);
```

Jackson successfully deserializes the JSON string to a **B** object and assigns a reference of type **Base**.

But the moment that I try to do the same kind of deserialization, but for a collection, I get an exception:

```
String testJSON = "[{\"id\": \"someId\",\"description\": \"someDescription\",\"type\": \"B\"}, {\"id\": \"anotherId\",\"description\": \"anotherDescription\",\"type\": \"B\"}]";
List<Base> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(testJSON, new TypeReference<List<Base>>(){});
```

> org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.mycomp...Base, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

In other words, the moment I try to deserialize a JSON array containing different types of objects into a container of base type Jackson throws an exception.

I tried tweaking a lot of things, but nothings seems to fix it.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I removed JPA annotations and implements of your custom interface and your example works fine. What does your interface contains?

Comment: agree previous, guess that this is the key to the problem `implements IJPAEntity<String>, Jsonable`

Comment: My Jsonable interface contains a single ```toJson()``` method which simply converts the current object to a JSON string(serializes the current object).

Comment: ```default String toJson() {
  try {
   return new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL).writeValueAsString(this);
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }```

Comment: Not sure how to edit that comment properly, sorry..

Comment: Did you try remove all JPA annotations and remove implementing of interfaces? Maybe it can helps to problem.

Comment: But it can helps you localize place that cause of error :)

Comment: Try putting Base[].class in the readValue() method, and on left hand side replcae List with an array Base[]